# Why does text in my Word document look terrible compared with the preview in the font dialog?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, formatting

I'm having a rather unusual issue with Microsoft Word. My text looks really nice in the preview section of the font dialog box but in the document it appears far more bold and condensed. Does anyone know why this might be happening? It looks absolutely awful in the document and when it is printed.

Here is some sample text. The upper text is that of the document and the lower text is of the font dialog.

[image]

I'd love it if anyone knows how to fix this so the font looks nice in the document itself (or at least when it is printed).

Answer (score 0):

It appears I have found a solution. Converting the font from OpenType to TrueType appears to have resolved the issue and the text is now rendering correctly. I'm not really sure why Word was struggling so much the first time but oh, well - all fixed now.